# Is it possible to generate complete url from http response header

Tags: http, url, filter, network-programming, http-headers

I wish to get the complete url of file being set by server through its http-header(response). I am doing some sort of packet filtering. Is it possible to generate complete url from http response header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You need the actual HTTP request.

Comment: But QNetworkReply class can do that:   QUrl QNetworkReply::url () const
Returns the URL of the content downloaded or uploaded. Note that the URL may be different from that of the original request.

Comment: @adnankamili the original URI is not in the response, so if you have an API that provides this information then it's because it has access to the request

Comment: @adnankamili you can read through HTTP standard  (RFC or some tutorial showing header and payload fields) of get and response messages. The response never contains url. In fact it is possible for a single url to be spread across multiple get packets. These are assembled together when needed.

Comment: I am intercepting netwprk packets using iptables queue option based on matching string contained in packet, i want to direct the packet info to other app to take on the request. Does this mean it is impossible using this method!